# How can I query a value in SQL Server XML column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have following XML stored in a XML column (called `Roles`) in a SQL Server database.

```
<root>
   <role>Alpha</role>
   <role>Beta</role>
   <role>Gamma</role>
</root>
```

I'd like to list all rows that have a specific role in them. This role passed by parameter.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

```
select
  Roles
from
  MyTable
where
  Roles.value('(/root/role)[1]', 'varchar(max)') like 'StringToSearchFor'
```

In case your column is not `XML`, you need to convert it. You can also use other syntax to query certain attributes of your XML data. Here is an example...

Let's suppose that data column has this:

```
<Utilities.CodeSystems.CodeSystemCodes iid="107" CodeSystem="2" Code="0001F" CodeTags="-19-"..../>
```

... and you only want the ones where `CodeSystem = 2` then your query will be:

```
select 
  [data] 
from
  [dbo].[CodeSystemCodes_data]
  
where
  CAST([data] as XML).value('(/Utilities.CodeSystems.CodeSystemCodes/@CodeSystem)[1]', 'varchar(max)') = '2'
```

These pages will show you more about how to query XML in T-SQL:

[Querying XML fields using t-sql](http://www.brokenwire.net/bw/Programming/125/querying-xml-fields-using-t-sql)

[Flattening XML Data in SQL Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2009/04/24/flattening-xml-data-in-sql-server.aspx)

**EDIT**

After playing with it a little bit more, I ended up with this amazing query that uses [CROSS APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx). This one will search every row (role) for the value you put in your like expression...

Given this table structure:

```
create table MyTable (Roles XML)

insert into MyTable values
('<root>
   <role>Alpha</role>
   <role>Gamma</role>
   <role>Beta</role>
</root>')
```

We can query it like this:

```
select * from 

(select 
       pref.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(32)') as RoleName
from 
       MyTable CROSS APPLY

       Roles.nodes('/root/role') AS Roles(pref)
)  as Result

where RoleName like '%ga%'
```

You can check the SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dc4d2/1/0

Comment: It answers all my question, what does `[1]` do in your answer?

Comment: Great answer, I vote for this one, but string should be varchar I guess

Comment: @Bistro Asking about `[1]` was a really good question. It means that you pick the first role value from the XML and that means that this will only work for finding `Alpha` in your sample xml. It will not find the row if you search for `Beta`.

Comment: In my case, I had to query nodes with specific attribute value. This answer was the lead to my solution. I just had to put double quotes around the attribute value.

Comment: If the XML has a namespace, how do we query it?

Comment: Getting - "Cannot call methods on nvarchar(max)". Can anyone please suggest

Comment: @AbhilashV you need to convert that to XML: `CAST([data] as XML).value...`

Answer (score 40):

```sql
declare @T table(Roles xml)

insert into @T values
('<root>
   <role>Alpha</role>
   <role>Beta</role>
   <role>Gamma</role>
</root>')

declare @Role varchar(10)

set @Role = 'Beta'

select Roles
from @T
where Roles.exist('/root/role/text()[. = sql:variable("@Role")]') = 1
```

If you want the query to work as `where col like '%Beta%'` you can use `contains`

```sql
declare @T table(Roles xml)

insert into @T values
('<root>
   <role>Alpha</role>
   <role>Beta</role>
   <role>Gamma</role>
</root>')

declare @Role varchar(10)

set @Role = 'et'

select Roles
from @T
where Roles.exist('/root/role/text()[contains(., sql:variable("@Role"))]') = 1
```

Answer (score 13):

if your field name is Roles and table name is table1 you can use following to search

```
DECLARE @Role varchar(50);
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE Roles.exist ('/root/role = sql:variable("@Role")') = 1
```

Comment: this is good, is here any way to search the using `like`? `forexample /root/role like ....`

Comment: use `.value('(/root/role)[1]', 'varchar(max)') like '%yourtext%'` instead of `exists` as Leniel explained

Comment: Have you tried this? It finds everything, regardless of what you put in `@Role`.

Answer (score 11):

I came up with a simple work around below which is easy to remember too   :-)

```
select * from  
(select cast (xmlCol as varchar(max)) texty
 from myTable (NOLOCK) 
) a 
where texty like '%MySearchText%'
```

Comment: We're not supposed to search via string manipulation, as that would result in way too slow searches

Answer (score 6):

You could do the following

```
declare @role varchar(100) = 'Alpha'
select * from xmltable where convert(varchar(max),xmlfield) like '%<role>'+@role+'</role>%'
```

Obviously this is a bit of a hack and I wouldn't recommend it for any formal solutions. However I find this technique very useful when doing adhoc queries on XML columns in SQL Server Management Studio for SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Useful tip. Query a value in SQL Server XML column (XML with namespace)

e.g.

```
Table [dbo].[Log_XML] contains columns Parametrs (xml),TimeEdit (datetime)
```

e.g. XML in Parametrs:

```
<ns0:Record xmlns:ns0="http://Integration"> 
<MATERIAL>10</MATERIAL> 
<BATCH>A1</BATCH> 
</ns0:Record>
```

e.g. Query:

```
select
 Parametrs,TimeEdit
from
 [dbo].[Log_XML]
where
 Parametrs.value('(//*:Record/BATCH)[1]', 'varchar(max)') like '%A1%'
 ORDER BY TimeEdit DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the below statement to retrieve the values in the XML in the Sql table

```
with xmlnamespaces(default 'http://test.com/2008/06/23/HL.OnlineContract.ValueObjects')
select * from (
select
            OnlineContractID,
            DistributorID,
            SponsorID,
    [RequestXML].value(N'/OnlineContractDS[1]/Properties[1]/Name[1]', 'nvarchar(30)') as [Name]
   ,[RequestXML].value(N'/OnlineContractDS[1]/Properties[1]/Value[1]', 'nvarchar(30)') as [Value]
     ,[RequestXML].value(N'/OnlineContractDS[1]/Locale[1]', 'nvarchar(30)') as [Locale]
from [OnlineContract]) as olc
where olc.Name like '%EMAIL%' and olc.Value like '%EMAIL%' and olc.Locale='UK EN'
```

Comment: What if XML does not contain Namespace definition ?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the whole tag, or just the specific value. Here I use a wildcard for the xml namespaces.

```
declare @myDoc xml
set @myDoc = 
'<Root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://stackoverflow.com">
    <Child>my value</Child>
 </Root>'

select @myDoc.query('/*:Root/*:Child') -- whole tag
select @myDoc.value('(/*:Root/*:Child)[1]', 'varchar(255)') -- only value
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to find other node besides "Alpha", the query should be something like this:

`select Roles from MyTable where Roles.exist('(/*:root/*:role[contains(.,"Beta")])') = 1`