# Querying a table that contains an XML column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains an xml column, my table looks like the following:

```
MyTable
    Id(Pk, int,not null)
    Name(varchar(50), not null)
    Value(XML(.), not null)
```

The type of **Value** is **XML**

I've tried the following query and of course it is not working

```
/****** Script ******/
SELECT TOP 1000 [Id]
      ,[Name]
      ,[Value]
  FROM [Value]
  where Value like '%something%'
```

How can I get columns that contains **something** in their xml value

Comment: Where do you to find `%something%`?  In an element value? An element name? An attribute name?

Comment: something is a string , but CAST(Value AS VARCHAR(MAX)) worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work?  I'm assuming you meant to select FROM MyTable, not from [Value]:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Id]
    ,[Name]
    ,[Value]
FROM [MyTable]
where CAST(Value AS VARCHAR(MAX)) like '%something%'
```

Comment: Great ! Worked like a charm , txs :)

Answer (score 0):

XML

```
<root>
<role>Alpha</role>
<role>Beta</role>
<role>Gamma</role>
</root>

select  [Name]  ,[Value]
from  Value
where  Value.value('(/root/role)[1]', 'varchar(max)') like '%Beta%'
```

also refer [How can I query a value in SQL Server XML column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344553/how-can-i-query-a-value-in-sql-server-xml-column)