# Extracting specific text from a column

Tags: sql, xml

I am not sure if this is possible or not.

I have a column in a table that contains a lot of XML, but I only want a single part of the XML.

Is there a way that I can get that one bit of XML and get rid of the rest?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: also add some example strings and tell us what part exactly it is you need to get out of there

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I query a value in SQL Server XML column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344553/how-can-i-query-a-value-in-sql-server-xml-column)